# How can I reload the store after creating a resource at runtime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form, react-admin

I am fetching the resources at run time via an api call. I have a `create` view that creates a resource. How do I reload the `react-admin redux store` so that the sidebar gets updated with the new resource?

I thought of following the example [here](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/16198fd9fbc74b952e03dd17db14e9e8a822c374/docs/Actions.md#altering-the-form-values-before-submitting)

```
const saveWithNote = (values, basePath, redirectTo) => {
    console.log('creating new dataset...')
    crudCreate('datasets', values, basePath, redirectTo);
}
```

My thought was to fire some action here that could trigger a store state change and reload the page but I get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
(anonymous function)
/form/formMiddleware.js:21
  18 | var previousLocation;
  19 | return function (next) {
  20 |   return function (action) {
> 21 |     if (action.type !== LOCATION_CHANGE || action.payload.state && action.payload.state.skipFormReset) {
     | ^  22 |       return next(action);
  23 |     } // history allows one to redirect to the same location which can happen
  24 |     // when using a special menu for a create page for instance. In this case,
```

Here is my toolbar

```
const DatasetCreateToolbar = props => {

    return (
        <Toolbar {...props} >
            <SaveWithNoteButton
            label=" Save "
            redirect="list"
            submitOnEnter={false}
            variant="flat"
        />
        </Toolbar>
    )
};
```

The rest of the code is as is from the example [link](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/16198fd9fbc74b952e03dd17db14e9e8a822c374/docs/Actions.md#altering-the-form-values-before-submitting)

Is there a better way to trigger a store reload to get my sidebar to show the new resources created?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why I was getting an error.

```
const saveWithNote = (values, basePath, redirectTo) => {
    console.log('creating new dataset...')
    crudCreate('datasets', values, basePath, redirectTo);
}
```

I was calling the `crudCreate` function instead of returning it.

The code should have been

```
const saveWithNote = (values, basePath, redirectTo) => {
    console.log('creating new dataset...')
    return crudCreate('datasets', values, basePath, redirectTo);
}
```

I am still not sure what to do to refresh my store and reload the sidebar